# Using Cast As Date vs DateTime for a Between

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is this:

```
between cast(date as date) and cast(date1 as date)
```

The same as:

```
between '01/01/01 00:00:00' and '01/01/01 11:59:59'
```

I've been told that when comparing date time values in SQL Server that if I wanted to return the PROPER results I should ALWAYS include a time component with my date.

Comment: All dates will compare as dates. Is that what you have?

Comment: So a datetime that has been cast as a date will compare as a DATE? The same way that having a time component with midnight would?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql

Comment: No, they're not the same.  First, I assume you meant `23:59:59`?  Second, these two are clearly different: `'2018-03-15 18:18' BETWEEN '2018-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-03-15 23:59:59'` *(TRUE)* and `'2018-03-15 18:18' BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-15'` *(FALSE)*.  You could express it as `'2018-03-15 18:18' BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-16'`, but then `'2018-03-16 00:00:00'` now starts returning TRUE.  To use `BETWEEN` would need `CAST('2018-03-15 18:18' AS DATE) BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-15'`.  But wrapping search columns in functions is a bad idea.  Don't use `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `between` with dates.  It is just risky.  In general, the right syntax to use is:

```
where dtcol >= @date1 and
      dtcol < dateadd(day, 1, @date2)
```

Note the direction of the inequalities.  This works for columns that are both dates and date/times.  So, it just works.

Aaron Bertrand has an excellent blog post on this, [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: I've updated my question based on your response. My question regardless of syntax (thank you for the reference) is will stripping the time component out via a cast actually apply to the where clause?

Comment: You should strive to not modify the columns with expressions in your `WHERE` clause. If you do, the engine may ignore the indexes and have to do a full scan.

Comment: This is a fantastic point from a performance standpoint. thank you @Stavr00!

Answer (score 3):

Gordon is spot on. And I can demonstrate why with your own words. You wrote:

```
between '01/01/01 00:00:00' and '01/01/01 11:59:59'
```

To people who do not use 24 hour time regularly, this can easily appear to be correct logic. Unfortunately it has 2 problems. First and foremost, without an "AM/PM" designation, the default interpretation is **noon**. This is an easy mistake to make and one that might not be found during testing (developers are lazy - trust that).

Secondly, you specifically state datetime. What is the maximum possible time component of that datatype? Is it not what you have provided; rather it is 23:59:59.997. And what happens if someone changes the datatype to a more precise datetime2?

You might easily discard this concern as unlikely - and it is. But such edge cases have a habit of showing up eventually - and usually in situations where something has gone wrong. It is better to write code that is correct for the datatypes in use and not dependent on assumptions and luck.

I'll give a link to [Tibor's](http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes) datetime guide - whose site also contains lots of other excellent content worth reading when possible.

Answer (score 1):

No,

```
between cast(date as date) and cast(date1 as date)
```

is the same as:

```
between '20180310 00:00:00' and '20180315 00:00:00'
```

Between is inclusive of the values, it's the equivalent of:

```
@Dt >= '20180310 00:00:00' 
and @Dt <= '20180315 00:00:00'
```

Comment: You’re saying that that the two examples I presented are in fact identical in terms of the data that is returned? As previously mentioned the only downfall that I can see is performance in terms of doing a whole table scan and loss of indexing due to the function.

Comment: No, in your example, the value '20180315 00:00:00' would be returned in your first effort (between cast(date as date) and cast(date1 as date)) but not in your second (between '01/01/01 00:00:00' and '01/01/01 11:59:59')